# How to use/seperate Enums, constants & locators in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, webdriverjs

I am trying to make my tests more cleaner/parameterized by moving the enums, constants & locators to other files. Is there a way to do this while using protractor/java script. If yes, What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, follow the [Page Object pattern/model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html).

As for protractor specifically, study the ["Page Objects" chapter](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/style-guide.md#page-objects) of the Style Guide.